# How to simplify these two blocks of code into one?

Tags: javascript

```
$(".button-wrap.enter-now").click(isMobile ?
    function(){
        window.location = 'form/form.html';
    }
    : function(){
        TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.35, {startAt:{top:0}, opacity:1 });
        TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, {top:"8%", delay:0.05, ease:Power3.easeOut, opacity:1});
});
$("#close-form").click(function(){
    TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, {opacity:0, top:"110%", ease:Power3.easeOut});
    TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.25, {opacity:0, delay:0.1});
    TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.01, {top:"120%", delay:0.45});
});
```

I have the above code for non-ie8s, and below for ie8 - they look exactly the same except that there is no opacity in the tweens:

```
if(ie8){
    $(".button-wrap.enter-now").click(isMobile ?
        function(){
            window.location = 'form/form.html';
        }
        : function(){
            TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.35, {startAt:{top:0} });
            TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, { top:"8%", delay:0.05, ease:Power3.easeOut});
    });
    $("#close-form").click(function(){
        TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, {top:"110%", ease:Power3.easeOut});
        TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.25, { delay:0.1});
        TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.01, {top:"120%", delay:0.25});
    });
}
```

I just wonder, how can I simplify the code into one? I don't even know what to search for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should search for the ternary operator.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: He's already using it, or abusing it I'd say...

Comment: @DannyBeckett You mean the x?x:x expression? I know this one. But how can I extract {opacity: 1} from the object?

Comment: @elclanrs: how to not-abuse it? thanks!

Comment: By using an `if..else` statement instead.

Comment: @elclanrs sorry I've just started learning, why's if/else better?

Comment: Well, IMO it's more about what's easier to read and understand. A ternary operator is fine for a quick expression, but you have like 7 lines there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, just use variables to hold the objects and set the opacity if IE8 is detected.

```
$(".button-wrap.enter-now").click(isMobile ?
    function(){
        window.location = 'form/form.html';
    }
    : function(){
        var attrA = {startAt:{top:0}};
        var attrB = {top:"8%", delay:0.05, ease:Power3.easeOut};
        if (ie8 /* In case ie8 is not working for you: $.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 8*/) {
            attrA.opacity = 1;
            attrB.opacity = 1;
        }
        TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.35, attrA);
        TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, attrB);
});
$("#close-form").click(function(){
    var attrA = {top:"110%", ease:Power3.easeOut};
    var attrB = {delay:0.1};
    if (ie8) {
        attrA.opacity = 0;
        attrB.opacity = 0;
    }
    TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, attrA);
    TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.25, attrB);
    TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.01, {top:"120%", delay:0.45});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look for patterns in your code, and rearrange. For instance, you have one element with a click listener; do that once. You have the same check for mobile once you click; do that once.  etc. So, for your `.button-wrap.enter-now` you could have one function with something like this:

```
$(".button-wrap.enter-now").click(function(){
  if(isMobile){
    window.location = 'form/form.html';
  }else if(ie8){
    TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.35, {startAt:{top:0} });
    TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, { top:"8%", delay:0.05, ease:Power3.easeOut});
  }else{
    TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.35, {startAt:{top:0}, opacity:1 });
    TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, {top:"8%", delay:0.05, ease:Power3.easeOut, opacity:1});
  }
});
```

You could also combine those `TweenMax`'s even further, but I wanted to keep it simpler and I hope you get the gist. Now you should be able to do the same for your `#close-form` click handler as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just encapsulate the opacity in an `if-else` statement.

```
$(".button-wrap.enter-now").click(isMobile ? function(){
        window.location = 'form/form.html';
    }
    : function(){
        TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.35, {startAt:{top:0}, opacity:1 });
        TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, {top:"8%", delay:0.05, ease:Power3.easeOut, opacity:1});
});

$("#close-form").click(function(){
    TweenMax.to($("#form-wrapper"), 0.45, {opacity:0, top:"110%", ease:Power3.easeOut}); 
    if(ie8){
        TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.25, {delay:0.1});
    }else{
        TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.25, {opacity:0, delay:0.1});
    }
    TweenMax.to($iframeBg, 0.01, {top:"120%", delay:0.45});
});
```